# passing folder path from an asp file

Tags: asp-classic

I am using this code to navigate through the folders available on a remote computer.

```
 <%@ Language=VBScript %><%
option explicit
dim sRoot, sDir, sParent, objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objSubFolder, sSize
%>
<META content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0" name=GENERATOR><!-- Author: Adrian Forbes --> 
<%


sRoot = "\\iflblw-bpd-12\Vercon_IP-BPD-01\SOFT"


sDir = Request("Dir")


sDir = sDir & "\"

Response.Write "<h1>" & sDir & "</h1>" & vbCRLF


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
on error resume next

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sRoot & sDir)
if err.number <> 0 then
    Response.Write "Could not open folder"
    Response.End
end if
on error goto 0


sParent = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFolder.Path)

' Remove the contents of sRoot from the front.  This gives us the parent
' path relative to the root folder
' eg. if parent folder is "c:webfilessubfolder1subfolder2" then we just want "subfolder1subfolder2"
sParent = mid(sParent, len(sRoot) + 1)

Response.Write "<table border=""1"">"

' Give a link to the parent folder.  This is just a link to this page only pssing in
' the new folder as a parameter
Response.Write "<tr><td colspan=3><a href=""browse.asp?dir=" & Server.URLEncode(sParent) & """>Parent folder</a></td></tr>" & vbCRLF

' Now we want to loop through the subfolders in this folder
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    ' And provide a link to them
    Response.Write "<tr><td colspan=3><a href=""browse.asp?dir=" & Server.URLEncode(sDir & objSubFolder.Name) & """>" & objSubFolder.Name & "</a></td></tr>" & vbCRLF
Next

' Now we want to loop through the files in this folder
'For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'    if Clng(objFile.Size) < 1024 then
 '       sSize = objFile.Size & " bytes"
  '  else
   '     sSize = Clng(objFile.Size / 1024) & " KB"
    'end if
    ' And provide a link to view them.  This is a link to show.asp passing in the directory and the file
    ' as parameters
   ' Response.Write "<tr><td><a href=""show.asp?file=" & server.URLEncode(objFile.Name) & "&dir=" & server.URLEncode (sDir) & """>" & objFile.Name & "</a></td><td>" & sSize & "</td><td>" & objFile.Type & "</td></tr>" & vbCRLF
'Next

Response.Write "</table>"
%>
```

I want to pass the folder path to a form on another page. Actually, while filling out the form this page should be called. How do you pass the path?

For example, what I need is when a user wants to select a folder he clicks a button which calls this page. On selecting the folder the folder's path should be returned to the form.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Might wanna work on formatting your code there, bud. Hit edit, highlight your code, and then click the button above the text box that has all the 1's and 0's on it.

Comment: thanks for telling. but i dunno how to highlight the comments

Comment: Click the little orange ? box on the upper right of the "Your Answer" posting box. It will have plenty of guidance to get you started formatting your postings :D

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing the folder path on your code here:

```
<a href=""browse.asp?dir=" & Server.URLEncode(sDir & objSubFolder.Name) & """>" 
& objSubFolder.Name & "</a>
```

On the browser.asp page you can get the folder using:

```
sDir = Request("Dir")
```